# ASP.NET MVC4: How to hightlight selected row and send id corresponding to controller when click on edit or detail or delete link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need help please. I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4. I have a view(Index.cshtml) that display data in table from sql database using entity framework. I want to know how to hightlight selected row and send specific id(id_equipment) to one html.actionlink for editing, deleting or viewing details.
Here's my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TEST.Models.equipment>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = /*item.id_equipment*/ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = /*item.id_equipment*/ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = /*item.id_equipment*/ })
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id_equipment)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.type)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id_equipment)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.type)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at adding a controller with CRUD, this will generate all the views with the ActionLinks with the ID attached to edit,delete,details etc?